# Why does @Value not injecting property value in spring multi-module application

Tags: spring

I have maven project with two modules: mmmp-servive and mmmp-web. Both of them using spring (not spring-boot). mmmp-web depends on mmmp-service and build as war-file. Here is my mmmp-web pom.xml file:

```xml
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>ru.monsterdev</groupId>
    <version>1.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>mmmp-web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- PROJECT -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ru.monsterdev</groupId>
      <artifactId>mmmp-service</artifactId>
      <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- COMMON -->
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SLF4J -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring-security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-cas-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  <build>
    <finalName>MMMPWeb##${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And this is my mmmp-service pom.xml file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>ru.monsterdev</groupId>
        <version>1.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>mmmp-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- COMMON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>xlsx</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In my mmmp-service module i have classes AppConfig, HttpService and application.property file:

AppConfig:

```java
package ru.monsterdev.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
}
```

Httpservice:

```java
package ru.monsterdev.servises.impl;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import ru.monsterdev.servises.IHttpService;

@Service
public class HttpService implements IHttpService {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpService.class);

  @Value("${app.service.url}")
  private String url;

  @Override
  public String getRequestBody(String param) {
    LOGGER.debug("URL is {}", url);
    return param;
  }
}
```

and application.property
app.service.url=http://some-url/

In my mmmp-web i am using autowired HttpService into Controller class

```java
package ru.monsterdev.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import ru.monsterdev.servises.IHttpService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IntexController {
  @Autowired
  private IHttpService httpService;

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String indexAction(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("response", httpService.getRequestBody("Hello"));
    return "index";
  }
}
```

OK, when i deploy and startup my war on tomcat is failed because app.service.url is not found. Can you explay me why spring does not resolve it?